# get array of particular key from List<Map<String,dynamic>> in DART

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list with the below values:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> arrayTest = [{'id':'1','name':'test1'},{'id':'2','name':'test2'},{'id':'3','name':'test3'},{'id':'4','name':'test5'}];
```

I want to get all `id` values from the arrayTest variable into another `List<dynamic>` type list.

I'm new to flutter, I've tried the `.map()` function but not getting any idea how to do this.

Comment: you should write a class model for your Map items

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will help you !

```
List<dynamic> newList= arrayTest.map((m)=>m['id']).toList();
//replace m['id'] with your field !
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you wanted, also please add expected output in your asked question.

Is that what you wanted:

```
void main() {
List<Map<String,dynamic>> arrayTest = [{'id':'1','name':'test1'},{'id':'2','name':'test2'},{'id':'3','name':'test3'},{'id':'4','name':'test5'}];

  List list=[];
  for(var array in arrayTest){
    list.add(array['name']);

  }
  print(list);
}

OR
without for loop

void main() {
List<Map<String,dynamic>> arrayTest = [{'id':'1','name':'test1'},{'id':'2','name':'test2'},{'id':'3','name':'test3'},{'id':'4','name':'test5'}];


  List list= arrayTest.map((array)=>array['name']).toList();
  print(list);
}
```

output:

```
[test1, test2, test3, test5]
```

Comment: can we achieve this without using for loop