# how can i collect all the kg values from map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

how can i collect all the kg values from map in dart?

```
final List<Map> listOfColumns = [
{
  "Name": "Hurda",
  "KG": 55.000,
  "Al": 1.52,
  "Si": 0,
  "Fe": 0,
  "Cu": 0,
  "Mg": 0,
  "Zn": 0,
  "Mn": 0,
  "Cr": 0
},
{
  "Name": "Araiş",
  "KG": 55.000,
  "Al": 1.52,
  "Si": 0,
  "Fe": 0,
  "Cu": 0,
  "Mg": 0,
  "Zn": 0,
  "Mn": 0,
  "Cr": 0
},
{
  "Name": "Külçe",
  "KG": 55.000,
  "Al": 1.52,
  "Si": 0,
  "Fe": 0,
  "Cu": 0,
  "Mg": 0,
  "Zn": 0,
  "Mn": 0,
  "Cr": 0
},
{
  "Name": "Araiş",
  "KG": 55.000,
  "Al": 1.52,
  "Si": 0,
  "Fe": 0,
  "Cu": 0,
  "Mg": 0,
  "Zn": 0,
  "Mn": 0,
  "Cr": 0
},
{
  "Name": "Biyet Başı",
  "KG": 55.000,
  "Al": 1.52,
  "Si": 0,
  "Fe": 0,
  "Cu": 0,
  "Mg": 0,
  "Zn": 0,
  "Mn": 0,
  "Cr": 0
},
];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is the code you already tried to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get array of particular key from List<Map<String,dynamic>> in DART](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60349846/get-array-of-particular-key-from-listmapstring-dynamic-in-dart)

Comment: var kgs = listOfColumns.map((x) => x['KG']);

Comment: See [ask] to improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<double> collectedKgs = listOfColumns.map((e)=>double.tryParse(e["KG"])?? 0.0).toList();
```

This accounts for errors or bad formats in your inputs, if something is not a double, because Kgs are doubles based on your Map.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newLIst = listOfColumns.map((object)=>object['KG']).toList();
```